# Is there a shortcut syntax for checking types of variables?

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, how do I say:

```
if (typeof obj === 'number' 
    || typeof obj === 'boolean' 
    ||  typeof obj === 'undefined' 
    || typeof obj === 'string') {
```

In other words, is there some kind of:

```
if (typeof obj in('number','boolean','undefined','string')) {
```

Comment: Are you looking to improve on the first statement?

Comment: Just curious -- why do you need to check for so many types? I've never had to do this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More grist for the mill:

```
if ( ('object function string undefined').indexOf(typeof x) > -1) {
  // x is an object, function, string or undefined
}
```

or

```
if ( (typeof x).match(/object|function|string|undefined/)) {
  // x is an object, function, string or undefined
}
```

How many ways do you want this cat skinned?

Comment: Note that these would also match any type that happened to be a substring of any of the four type names.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a `switch`:

```
switch (typeof obj) {
  case 'number':
  case 'boolean':
  case 'undefined':
  case 'string':
    // You get here for any of the four types
    break;
}
```

In Javascript 1.6:

```
if (['number','boolean','undefined','string'].indexOf(typeof obj) !== -1) {
  // You get here for any of the four types
}
```

Comment: Switch statements should always have a default block.

Comment: Yes, just a convention, probably more to be consistent with other languages and make it clear what happens if all cases fail.

Comment: I think Crockford says not to use the switch statement because it requires a break at the end of every case.

Answer (score 4):

You could approximate it with something like

```
var acceptableTypes = {'boolean':true,'string':true,'undefined':true,'number':true};

if ( acceptableTypes[typeof obj] ){
  // whatever
}
```

or the more verbose

```
if ( typeof obj in acceptableTypes){
  // whatever
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. `typeof(obj)` just returns a string, so you can simply do as you would when checking if a string is in any set of strings:

```
if (typeof(obj) in {'number':'', 'boolean':'', 'undefined':'', 'string':''})
{
  ...
}
```

Or you could make it even shorter. Since the only "types" that `typeof` may return are `number`, `string`, `boolean` `object`, `function` and `undefined`, in this particular case, you could just make an exclusion instead.

```
if (!(typeof(obj) in {'function':'', 'object':''}))
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: *typeof* is an operator, there is no need for a grouping operator so `typeof obj` is sufficient and prefered.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use functional programming for similar situations.
So you can use [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#any) to make it more readable:

```
_.any(['number','boolean','undefined','string'], function(t) {
  return typeof(obj) === t; 
});
```